# Workstation is not accepting image

Tags: windows-7, imaging, mdt-2010

I am in the process of a Win 7 migration using MDT and the last workstation is having a problem reimaging. I am getting an error message saying the installation was canceled windows cannot not install, make sure all files are available before starting installation.  We tried reimaging the workstation twice, but it will not reimage. All 27 other workstations were completed successfully,

It is also giving him an error code: `0X80070570`

Wiping goes fine but reimaging process will not complete.

ERROR: "Wizard error: unable to find the sms task sequencer. The deployment will not proceed."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try wiping out the contents of the hard drive, at least by removing the partition table. 
I've often seen issues like this crop up when a few remnants of a previous MDT installation are present.

I keep a copy of [DBAN](http://dban.org) on my MDT server just in case this crops up. 
If you go the DBAN route you only need to let it run for about a minute.

Comment: You don't need dban to clean a disk, just open a command prompt and run diskpart, select disk 0, clean - should take a second at best.  You can run a script with this as well

Comment: I realise that... I use dban to wipe my disks for disposal. It also does a good job for this particular task (if overkill).

Answer (score 1):

When I get this error I usually delete the the two folders created by the MDT process and start afresh.

- C:\Minint
- C:_SMSTaskSequence

I boot into the system using Hiren BOOT CD and delete the folders.

Answer (score 0):

Did you PXE boot?  I suspect you are having a network error on that workstation.